# HAproxy transparent mode standalone setup

Tags: routes, centos, transparency, iptables, haproxy

I'm trying to setup HAproxy transparent mode with backend servers for localhost. I understand how transparent mode works for backend server having gateway address pointing to the HAproxy server but for standalone mode with backend settings to  localhost server I have no idea how to set it up.

My Setting for HAproxy transparent mode

> iptables rules

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
```

> IP route rules

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

> HAProxy configuration

```
source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
server 127.0.0.1:80
```

What do I have to do to make HAproxy transparent mode work for backend servers to be localhost(standalone) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I has a same task, here is configuration that will let haproxy work as transparent proxy for local services

```
#Basic configuration
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 4096
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    timeout client 5s
    timeout server 5s
    timeout connect 5s

frontend forwarder
    bind *:1025
    mode http
    default_backend proxy

backend proxy
     option httpclose
     option http_proxy
     mode http
```